# Integer resultant by double division

Tags: java

I am trying to achieve this operation:

```
360 / 1000000 = 0.00000036
90 / 0.00000036 = 250000000
```

This is my code so far-

```
int n = 1000000;
double ex_angle = 360 / (double) n;
int res = 90 / ex_angle;
System.out.println ("res: " + res);
```

My IDE isn't allowing me to write `int res = 90 / ex_angle` which is logical as `ex_angle` is a `double` and `res` is an `int`.
But I also can't do this-

```
int res = 90 / (int) ex_angle
```

Because this casting will cause the "division by zero exception."

Can anyone please help me to get the desired result?

Comment: You could write `int res = (int) (90 / ex_angle);` which means casting the result of the arithmetic operation to an `int` instead of casting a single operand...

Comment: How about `n/4` ? 90 / ( 360 / n ) = 90 * ( n / 360 ) = 0.25 * n ... or even n >> 2

Comment: Note: you could turn the whole thing around: 90*1000000 / 360 ... works with all int arithmetic.

Comment: @deHaar thanks but my IDE is still showing me the error `required type int, provided double`

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Consider using `BigDecimal` for these calculations

Comment: @deHaar IntelliJ IDEA with Java 11.0.5

Comment: Hmm... my eclipse doesn't show any error... Are you sure it's that line?

Comment: @deHaar yes, I'm afraid that is the line the IDE is showing me

Comment: Mind: You'll probably see floating point error in going through double-division. So your result may be 24999999 instead of 25000000 ...

Comment: @GhostCat I need the values of the variables `ex_angle` and `res` later in my code. I understand your comment but that would yield similar result for n<90. For these two reasons, I am intending to find a way to get the result straightforward way. Maybe Java has some tricks that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going the way you chose will introduce a lot of error.

Doing the math, you can simplyfy your equation *a lot*:

```
90 / ( 360 / n ) 
= 90 * ( n / 360 ) 
= 90 / 360 * n 
= 1/4 * n 
= n / 4
```

which can easily be done `int result = n / 4;`
or by shifting n right by 2 : `int result = n >> 2;` (just "nerdier", not necessarily more efficient).

If you need `ex_angle` (which is `360 / n`), I'd calculate that seperately, to keep error at a minimum.

Comment: "which can easily be done by shifting n right by 2" Sure; but dividing by 4 is more readable in the context of "doing regular maths" and no less efficient.

Comment: It *may* be no less efficient (the Java API code writers do it - for an example, take a look at  `AbstractStringBuilder reverse()`).  But saying it is more readable is pure opinion (and one with which I respectfully disagree).

Comment: Well, Andy does have a point here, I think. Especially very Junior devs may have a hard time with shift operations out of the blue.

Comment: Actually, I'd advise in production code to even not just drop the "magic number" 4 ... it may be not self-evident that it is the result of above transformation.